# HTML - center fixed element and provide width of the parent

Tags: html, css

I want to center a fixed div inside its parent. The width of the fixed div should have the width of its parent. But it does not work, what is wrong?

[**js** **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ah621x9t/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="center" >
            centered      
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
border:solid;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}

.wrap {
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

.center{
background: red;
position:  fixed;
bottom: 100px;
width: inherit;  
}
```

Comment: position: fixed elements are relative to the viewport, so they have no inherit knowledge of their parent's width, as it is considered to be the viewport. I can offer a JavaScript solution if you're open to using it.

Comment: Position fixed element wont inherit parent value unless you give them a specific width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `.wrap`'s width:

```
.wrap {
    height: 800px;
    width: inherit;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```